# Writing a program that computes the total weight of a cargo. C

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that computes the total weight of a cargo. The user will enter the number of boxes and
the weight of a box for each type of boxes they have. My code keeps repeating the "Enter the number of boxes" twice when prompting the user to enter the weight. How do I fix that? Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x,y,total=0; // variables

    {
        while(!(x==-1 || y==-1)){

            printf("Enter the number of boxes:");
            scanf("%d",&x);

            printf("Enter the weight(lbs):");
            scanf("&d",&y);

            total+=(x*y);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    if (x==-1 || y==-1) {  // when the user inputs -1, the next 
                         line will execute

        printf("The total weight is:%d",total);
    }
    printf("\n");

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the question here?
also please fix the code formatting

Comment: `while(!(x==-1 || y==-1))` is using *uninitialised variables* on the first iteration. Please enable compiler warnings!

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm new to this. My code keeps repeating the enter the number of boxes when it asks the user to enter the weight. How do I fix that?

Comment: As the first comment says: formatting the code might reveal that to humans.

Comment: `scanf("&d",&y);` -> `scanf("%d",&y);`

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your code following the comments other people wrote you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 0,y = 0,total=0; // variables


    while(!(x==-1 || y==-1)){
        printf("Enter the number of boxes:");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        printf("Enter the weight(lbs):");
        scanf("%d",&y);
        total+=(x*y);
    }
    printf("\n");


    if (x==-1 || y==-1) 
    {  // when the user inputs -1, the next  line will execute
        printf("The total weight is:%d",total);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

All I did was to write it more simply and nicely

Good luck with your homework

Answer (score 0):

here is some fixed code, though you will need these new headers to get it to work

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

so i think the problem you have is your input buffer is skipping the second value.
to combat this i have use fgets instead, as it is easier to work wit.

```
char input[3];
    int x = NULL;
    int y = NULL;
    int total = 0; // variables

    while (x == NULL || y == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Enter the number of boxes:");
        fgets(input, 3, stdin);

        input[strlen(input) - 1] = 0;
        x = atoi(input);

        printf("Enter the weight(lbs):");
        fgets(input, 3, stdin);

        input[strlen(input) - 1] = 0;
        y = atoi(input);

        total += (x*y);
    }
```

the 3 in the input array needs to be equal to the amount of characters you wish to accept + 2 (to account for /n/0 termination)

Comment: I appreciate your code, but we haven't covered any of stuff you included. Is this C++?

Comment: no that is all base C, fgets is just an alternitive input method that is safer, and atoi converts a string to an int

probably shouldn't post homework here though

Comment: Okay, I'm just struggling to form this simple code. Thanks for the help though.